# Using PHPExcelReader to parse file and store values in array - File not found

Tags: php, html

I am using PHPExcelReader to parse an excel file (chosen by the user from their local machine). PHP will take those values and store them in an array and then reorganize it and display it on the screen in the form of a table.

However, after I browse for a file, once I click "Submit", I get the error: `File not found`

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:15px">
<h2>Step 1: Import the file</h2>
<p>Once uploaded, the window will display a preview of the document. Please check to make sure the column
    headers match the data before uploading.</p>

<form action="../scripts/previewFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Preview File" name="submit">

    <div id="filePreview" style="height: 500px; overflow: scroll;">

    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

The previewFile.php file that is called:

```
function previewFile()
{
    $filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader;      // creates object instance of the class
    $excel->read($filePath);

}
```

**UPDATE**
The error was a 404 for the PHP file "previewFile.php" that is called as an action.

Not sure what's wrong with my URL `"../scripts/previewFile.php"`

Here's my schema:

```
root
   |_views
        |_default
            |_assets
            |_scripts
                 |_previewFile.php
            |_templates
                 |_step1.php <- the html file with the input tags
```

Comment: **fileToUpload** not *file* in `$filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: i realize now the error is not saying that it couldn't find the file i chose, but couldn't find the php parser file. updated the question.

Comment: Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader !== PHPExcel, so removing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input name is `fileToUpload`, and you are looking in the `$_FILES` array for `file`,  so it should be as follows:

```
function previewFile()
{
    $filePath = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];

    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader;      // creates object instance of the class
    $excel->read($filePath);

}
```

Comment: your a geniusssssssssssssss

Comment: he was being sarcastic as he thinks you stole his answer

Comment: i am aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: every one on the internet is so cynical.